# Normalize volume for YouTube videos

Tags: windows, video, audio, chrome, youtube

Every day I stumble upon YouTube videos where presenter is speaking quietly, so I have to raise the volume on my speakers. But then he starts to shout intensely, almost shattering my windows and scaring my neighbors across the street.

Is there a way or a tool to normalize the volume of videos that I watch on YouTube, so that volume differences will be in some predictable and configurable range.

I seen this feature in offline media players, like Media Player Classic and [VLC](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=91355), but they play local videos only.

Maybe there is some plugin for Chrome, or just application that can be installed on Windows to normalize the Chrome browser volume.

Comment: There is the [Levelator](http://www.conversationsnetwork.org/levelator) if you are willing to download the video and extract the audio for Levelator to do its magic.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Chrome addon [Magic Actions for YouTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magic-actions-for-youtube/abjcfabbhafbcdfjoecdgepllmpfceif?hl=en) is the closest thing I know of that I find helps a lot with this problem. It does not control the volume of the videos but it has an option to allow scrolling on the video to quickly adjust the volume and allows custom intervals. So a video is playing and some loud noise starts to play, instead of fumbling to mouse over the small volume button you can just mouse over the video and scroll down to lower the volume. It has saved my ears many times.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow Google still points me here when searching for browser volume normalisation. If it is news to anyone, [Audio Channel](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/audio-channel/hafdgamhnmiioimpcdhhbhgcjndgmphd/) is a Chrome addon worth checking out. It has a limiter option, which is not exactly what I wanted but does the job most of times.

Note: If you tend to switch between multiple tabs with audio like me,
in Options, turn off "Active Tab Background Control",
then click the addon icon after switching tabs.